# When a class template is instantiated, is a member template declaration also instantiated?

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation

So let's take a example :

```
template<typename T> struct foo
{
    template<typename X> void bar(void (T::*)()) {}
    template<typename X> void bar(X*) {}
    template<typename X> void bar(T**) {}
};

int main() { foo<int> p; }
```

Will above instantiation of `class foo<int>` instantiate member template **declaration** `bar` even though member itself is template? Any reference from standard will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you ask if the infinite `foo<int>::bar<X>` are instantiated ? The answer is no.

Comment: @Jarod42 no, just the declaration of member function template `bar`

Comment: Posted code does not compile

Comment: @jpo38 it compiles after edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

Citation from C++11 standard, [temp.inst] [14.7.1]:

> 1. ...
>      The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes the implicit instantiation of the
>      declarations, but not of the definitions, default arguments, or exception-specifications of the class member
>      functions, member classes, scoped member enumerations, static data members and member templates; and
>      it causes the implicit instantiation of the definitions of unscoped member enumerations and member anonymous unions.

The second part has some more info about exactly when the member template *definitions* are instantiated. (It generally happens implicitly, when they are used:)

> 2. Unless a member of a class template or a member template has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly
>      specialized, the specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist; in particular, the initialization (and any associated
>      side-effects) of a static data member does not occur unless the static data member is itself used in a way
>      that requires the definition of the static data member to exist.